# How to implement gravity for a folding object (time dependent)?

Tags: python, math, simulation, gravity, pymunk

I used Pygame to simulate an object that folds differently depending on time (two-dimensional, so you only see lines and joints). I would like to implement gravity so that this object "walks" on the ground.
The joints are "infinitely" stiff. They do not rotate under the influence of gravity ( + the beams/lines also do not bend due to gravity). (These are "rotated" by a sine function depending on time). By these rotations, however, a "running mechanism" can take place (e.g. the object rolls or a part carries the object forward by friction).
I have tried a lot of things with Pymunk, but haven't come up with anything useful. I would be incredibly grateful if someone had a solution and could share it with me!

[image: diagram]

Comment: So do you mean each "node" in the material just falls under normal gravity, as if it was say, a sphere ?  Is there any "bounce" once they collide with the bottom of the window ?

Comment: The joints are "infinitely" stiff. They do not rotate under the influence of gravity. (These are "rotated" by a sine function depending on time). By these rotations, however, a "running mechanism" can take place (e.g. the object rolls or a part carries the object forward by friction). I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I dont think I understand the problem? Looks like this could be represented by circle shapes connected by joints, or by segment shapes connected by joints. But from your question I guess something is not working out?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is "Rigid Body Collision", where you adjust the rigid body's angles over time.  There's some interesting reading here:  http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/courses/graphics-s09/Zaferakis/project/final.html probably a bunch of other places too.